# Catch HTTP redirect loop?

Tags: javascript, http, redirect, greasemonkey, http-redirect

I'm the user of a site S which I have no control of and which sometimes has an infinite redirect loop (page A redirects to page B, using a HTTP 302 code response, and page B redirects to page A). This redirect can be fixed by clearing the site cookies.

I was wondering if I could automate this process, using a Greasemonkey script for example.

Sample algorithm (but I don't know if it's feasible with the GM API): when the script detects a 302 on a page of S, it removes all cookies for the site S.

Comment: I've tried searching how to catch a redirect with greasemonkey on the web, but I haven't found anything yet, which is why I'm wondering if it's feasible.

Comment: If the redirect is implemented via http headers only, the browser doesn't even start constructing the page so I doubt GM would run a script.

Comment: And apart from using greasemonkey, is there any other way to do this in an automated way ?